# Nested buckets minio

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

Is there a way to create a nested bucket in minio using python?

I have not found exact documentation on how to do so however, I read some answer that one can create a folder (is that the same as a bucket?) inside a bucket using fput_object command.

I am not sure how to proceed! Super new to minio! Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer however, I will leave the solution here just in case someone else gets stuck at the same place.

It was a simple detail I missed about put_object.

A folder can be created while adding an object to a bucket!
Here is how,

minioclient.put_object(
bucket_name,
f"folder_name/" + "object_name",
data,
length
)

Comment: Yes. The `Key` of an object includes its _full path_. Folders do not actually exist in Minio / Amazon S3 -- objects can be created with any path and the folder magically 'appears'.